# While loop and Regular Expression Extractor Jmeter issue

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I need to run a loop until text in response data is Completed for a HTTP request. 
[image: This is my While Controller]

[image: This is my Regular Expression Extractor]

[image: This is my HTTP request]

[image: This is my Response Data and need to check COMPLETED text and stop the loop]

My while loop is going in infinite loop. I am not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use debug sampler and ensure the value is correctly captured as ' completed '. Your regular expression seems to be wrong. It should besomething  like:

Status:"(.*?)"

You can use  regular expression tester in response data to validate the regular expression.